# DirectQuery and Composite Models

Tags: powerbi

The Microsoft documentation for DirectQuery states the following:

*When importing data, it is possible to combine data from multiple sources into a single model, for example, to easily join some data from a corporate SQL Server database with some local data maintained in an Excel file. This is not possible when using DirectQuery. When selecting DirectQuery for a source, it will then only be possible to use data from that single source (such as a single SQL Server database).*

The documentation says that for DirectQuery only data from that single source can be used in the model. However, I thought with Composite models you could now mix DirectQuery and Import to bring data in from multiple sources.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that documentation is just a bit out of date. Composite modeling was [released in the November 2018 Update](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-november-2018-feature-summary) and I think technically it's still a preview feature.

You can read more about composite models here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-composite-models

Comment: In the link you provide, related to the November update, it says that Composite models are now generally available. So I guess the other documentation is out of date.

Comment: Yeah, their release schedule is pretty quick and it looks like the documentation doesn't always catch up right away.